# How to replace formula with value in cell using vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have complex formula calculating the value of a cell and it calculates the value for me.

I want to get rid of the formula from the cell and want to retain the calculated value.

I have :

```
Dim range As Excel.Range = getRange()
For Each cell in range
    ' What should do to retain the value and get rid of the formula in the cell.
Next cell
```

Comment: Is a duplicate question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844444/how-to-optimize-this-simple-but-horrible-implementation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
For Each cell in range
   cell.Value = cell.Value
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

If a VBA doesn't pay off, try

- pressing **F2** (edit) **F9** (calculate) **ENTER** (save value) for a single cell
- copy a range and PasteSpecial/Values onto itself for larger ranges