# How to optimize this simple but horrible implementation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, vba

I basically want to **remove the formula from the cells but want to retain the calculated values.**

SO, I implemented it easily and it works great but **REALLY SLOW.** (About 2 mins for 1800 cells)

I have :

```
Dim col As Excel.Range = getRange()
For Each cell In col
    cell.Value = cell.Value
Next
```

I tried to do this to the first cell and then autofill the rest, but that copied the value of 1st cell to the rest of the cells in column.

So, what shall I do to make it fast..

**I think there must be something related to Autofill that should do the trick.**

**Please help !!**

Comment: I am doing a lot of complex tasks, all are done in seconds only this simple task takes mins. Please Help !

Comment: `cell.Value = cell.Value` --- what this line is used for?

Comment: This line basically.. retains the value of the cell and looses the formula in the process.. its like a neat way of getting rid of the formula !!

Comment: This behaviour seems odd, you're probably right but x = x normally won't change x in any way, good ole' VBA being different I suppose.

Comment: Well you are not totally right and not totally wrong.. its like can't explain how it happens.. you need to read the API for this !

Comment: May be that is done because Excel fires up its automatic calculations whenever a value is assigned, so that automatic calculation drops the formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you happen to know the exact address of your range, or you can get it (maybe using getRange()?), this seemed to work for me to remove a formula from the cells while maintaining the result:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F15").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F15").Value
```

Comment: This one seriously seems very interesting and simple.. Let me try that and then I will let you know the results.. !

Comment: I don't know how to thankyou.. but it worked.. like a charm.. !

Comment: Good one, @PaulR! Simple and does the job ;)

Comment: This and the statement from the question could easily cause a dev's brain crash... Good 'ol Excel.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using `.Formula = .Value` instead of `.Value = .Value`.  That makes a lot more sense.  The delay is caused by each call to Excel.  If you minimise the calls to Excel, it will run faster.  There are only six calls to Excel in PaulR's code (Worksheets, Range and Value twice each.)  I always copy blocks of information out of Excel, process them, then return the results as a block to prevent these lengthy delays.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes Excel recalculates the whole sheet when a change is done. Temporarily disabling the automatic recalculation while doing this kind of operations can cut down execution times dramatically.

According to [this forum post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=86215&page=1)  it can be done with:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual 
 ' code here
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: I will try and let you know the results !!

Comment: +1, that's always a valid solution for performance issues in Excel.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed when playing about with Excel VBA that anything more than a few lines of code can really drag but by far the greatest increase in 'run speed' is;

```
Sub NoScreenRePainting()
    Application.ScreenUpdating=False

    'Your code here.

    Application.ScreenUpdating=True
End Sub
```

Other suggestions: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm

Comment: This seems to be a good tip to speed up the overall app.. !!
Thanks.. 

If you have more like this.. please post here !

Comment: Indeed that is what I found, flag this as the answer if it was the most helpful to you. The only others I am aware of are detailed at the [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm) provided

Comment: +1, that's always a valid solution for performance issues in Excel.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @Stuart... paste Special as values...

```
Dim oRange As Excel.Range

Set oRange = getRange()

oRange.Copy
oRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Notice that using the clipboard may be tricky... hopefully someone else knows a (fast) way to do it without using it.

Comment: this way is rude to the user - it uses the clipboard, throwing out whatever might have been in there

Comment: Agree, @Nick. But that was the option I had in the top of my head (as I mentioned). I realized that most of our SO VBA questions are related to particular home-made / small-office applications.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to select the range of values, `Copy` and then `Paste Special / Values`? That replaces the formula with the value, and should be more or less instantaneous.

Comment: Please explain.. this seems like the solution to my problem.. !!

Comment: +1 Stuart, @Yugal do a *copy* as normal, then choose *Paste Special* from your menu (it depends on your version of Excel, but it will somewhere close to the standard *Paste*). *Paste Special* gives you a popup from which you should check the *Values* option as in this screenshot: http://www.excelfunctions.net/image-files/Paste_Special_Options.PNG

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that all of your formulas have calculated their values, then copy and paste as values to remove the formulas and leave only the calculated values. Here is an example:

```
Public Sub RemoveFormulas()

    Dim RangeWithFormulas As Range

    Set RangeWithFormulas = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A1:A1800")

    RangeWithFormulas.Copy

    RangeWithFormulas.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @Adam, I believe our solutions are pretty much the same... aren't they?

Comment: Yep, you could say that. Do you want me to delete mine?

Comment: Don't worry @Adam, let's just review other answers next time to avoid dup information. The important thing is that you're trying to help too. ;)

Answer (score -2):

I should recomend you select all the cells with formulas and paste values, try this:

```
Sub RemoveFormula()
Dim cell As Range
    'Excel function to select cells with formulas
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Select 

    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Value = cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Clean and simple results.

Comment: Well, cell.Value = cell.Value is the statement that is consuming time.. and this is what we had to optimize.